# js package - interface to object

Tags: dart, dart-js-interop

Using https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/js to interface a js class in this manner, works fine:

```
@JS()
class ObjJS {
  external ObjJS();
  external String fullName();
}
```

Now I want to expose the method in an other class, so fare I only have solved this with duplication of the method. This works, but will grow, when more methods are added. Needed is some kind of mixin or inheritance, but not accepted for this interop class. `jselem` is the library name

```
class ObjDart {
  jselem.ObjJS _objJS = new jselem.ObjJS();

  String fullName(){
    return _objJS.fullName();
  }
}
```

Are there more elegant ways to solve this?

---

Update for better illustration

Things works, the question regards if there was better ways to expose the methods/properties of the interfaced Javascript class. The example above is just minimal, so not that illustrative. To get better illustration, take the `ChartDataSet` from here : https://github.com/google/chartjs.dart/blob/master/lib/chartjs.dart Just for illustration, let say with this, on the Dart side is created a Dart class `StreamChartDataSet`, which adds functionality for reading online data from an url. Since `StreamChartDataSet` can't inherit or mixin from `ChartDataSet` the solution above gives:

```
class StreamChartDataSet {
   ChartDataSet _chartDataSet;
   ...
   String get label => _chartDataSet.label;
   set label(fial String v) => _chartDataSet.label(v);
    ...
}
```

This are many methods and pure mechanical work. When finished with this, just to hope that `ChartSettings` goes unmodified :-) I am working with other things, but using Charjs.dart for illustration.

Comment: I don't understand what the problem is.

Comment: Hi, First of all, the link in the question was wrong, now corrected. This concerns the js 0.6 package, not dart:js. The minimal example was not that illustrative, so I have tried one, which hopefully is more illustrative.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To clarify, you want to be able to extend a `@JS()` annotated class, is that correct? I don't think works since the `@JS()` class doesn't really exist until compile-time.

A couple options:

1. Someone could develop a code generator that looks at a `@JS()`-annotated class, and remove the boilerplate by doing basically what you're doing for you. Not super elegant, but at least helps.
2. You could file a bug against package:js to support extending.

In my opinion though, I'm a huge supporter of composition over extension, especially over classes you don't directly control. For example, if the JS-API changes from fullName to firstName and lastName, you can maintain the same API by just changing your getter:

```
String fullName() => _js.firstName + _js.lastName;
```

It's up to you though.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Aha, yes the class is generated, this is apparent at debugging. Actually many cases could be solved with aggregation and then at method like `ChartDataSet get chartDataSet => _chartDataSet`. I will go for that otherwiser 1) could be done easy.